# reading properties file from JSTL

Tags: properties, jstl, taglib

I am trying to read a "properties file" form JSTL using taglib , but i can't access it

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
```

I've located the tld file correctly in the web.xml , am sure of this

```
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

The properties file name is msg. properties

```
<fmt:bundle basename="msg">
<fmt:message key="error.more" />
</fmt:bundle>
```

I keep getting

```
???error.more???
```

instead of the message in properties file

I think the problem is either in locating the properties file , 
or in the base name in

```
<fmt:bundle basename="msg">
```

where should I locate the properties file , and how can I make a reference to it in the code??

thanks everyone

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
> ```

This is the wrong URI. This is for the old JSTL 1.0 which is out of life for long. For JSTL 1.1 you should be using `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt`.

---

> I've located the tld file correctly in the web.xml , am sure of this
>
> ```
> <taglib>
> <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
> <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
> </taglib>
> ```

This is unnecessary when you fix the taglib URL. Remove it from your `web.xml` and remove all those loose TLD files as well. You should just have `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Or when you're using JSTL 1.2, just the `jstl-1.2.jar`. Nothing more needs to be done.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

> The properties file name is msg. properties
>
> ```
> <fmt:bundle basename="msg">
> <fmt:message key="error.more" />
> </fmt:bundle>
> ```
>
> I keep getting
>
> ```
> ???error.more???
> ```
>
> instead of the message in properties file I think the problem is either in locating the properties file , or in the base name in `<fmt:bundle basename="msg">` where should I locate the properties file, and how can I make a reference to it in the code?

Put it in the classpath. In your particular case, with the base name `msg`, you need to put the `msg.properties` files in the root of the classpath.

#### See also:

- [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   < fmt:bundle basename="msg"/>
   < fmt:message key="error.more" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) where should I locate the properties file?**
You have to keep property files inside your src directory. For example you have two property files for English and Danish named

> Messages_en.properties
>
> Messages_da.properties

inside a package named like below

> com.isuru.test.i18N.resources

**2) and how can I make a reference to it in the code?**

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="session"/>
<fmt:bundle basename="com.isuru.test.i18N.resources.Messages" scope="session">
<fmt:message key="error.more" />
```

This will print the relevant massage in English

Answer (score 1):

As Isuru says, you have to place the properties file in a package as if you were talking about a class.

I came with a weird problem, I had been referencing my properties file correctly but never got the correct output, what I discovered was that you have to follow the same package name format for your properties bundles, so if you have packages:

```
com.test.clients   
com.test.stores
```

You have to create something like:

```
com.test.i18n
```

You **CAN'T** do

```
other.test.i18n
```

Here you can store your property files

```
error.more.properties
error.more_es_MX.properties
```

And then referenced them as you would normally do:

```
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
<fmt:message key="error.more" />
```

Also here is a great answer on how to internationalize your web app

How to internationalize a java web application [How to internationalize a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by following the below steps. I placed the messages_en.properties file under src/main/resources folder and referred the properties file using this code below. I didn't considered any localization, so didn't mentioned anything related to this.

1. Refer the JSTL fmt uri in jsp.<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
2. Refer the bundle in jsp.
   < fmt:bundle basename="messages_en">
3. Use the keys defined in properties file.
   < fmt:message key="error.loginfailure">