# Why I have this internazionalization\localization problems using the fmt:message into a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, localization, jstl

I have the following problem related to the internazionalization\localization of an old Java web application.

So I have this situation: I have 2 very similar web application and I had to take a JSP page from the first one and copy it into the second one.

This JSP page contains something like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input id="myCheck" onclick="changeBoxAll(this)" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="emittente_fatt"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="mandataria"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="id"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="numero_fatt"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="data_invio"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="data_approvazione"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="data_documento"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="totale_fattura"/></th>
        <th><fmt:message key="stato"/></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

As you can see in the previous code it contains the  tag.

This tag belong to the JSTL tag library and it is used to maps key to localized message and performs parametric replacement.

So, for example, instead the  in the first application is shown **Invoice Issuer** (if the user is engligh) or **emittente_fatt=Emittente fattura** (if the user is italian).

In the first application (the orignal one from where I take my JSP putted into the second application) it works fine and these date are stored into 2 properties file that are respectivelly names:

- /src/config/l18n/messages_en.properties
- /src/config/l18n/messages_it.properties

(the first one is for the english version and the second one for the italian version).

So into the second web application I had not the **l18n** subfolder into the **/src/config/** folder so, when I perform the previous JSP page I saw the key of the message properties file (something like: **???emittente_fatt???** instead the value **Invoice Issuer**)

Ok, so I tryed to copy and paste the **l18n** folder (and all its content) and put it into the **/src/config/** of the second web application.

Now if from Intellij I work into my view I can see the link to the bundled **messages_en.properties** and **messages_it.properties** (CTRL + clicking on the key of the  **tag I can chose if open one of these file.**

So these properties file seems to be correctly bundled into the project.

The problem is that if I try to run my project I still see the key and not the associated value, I see something like this:

[image]

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue and correctly see the value into my th?

**EDIT-1**:

This is the web.xml content of the destionation webapp (the one in that the internazionalization can't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">    
<web-app>

    <display-name>MY APPLICATION NAME</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>messages</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.quartz.QuartzListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Monitoraggio</servlet-class>   
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/edimon.do/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Salwf</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/salwf.do/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/logon.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>

</web-app>
```

This is my entire JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<jsp:useBean id="Bean_Dati" scope="session" type="it.sistinf.ediweb.dbutil.GestoreDati"/>


<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld" prefix="display" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ page import="it.sistinf.ediweb.util.Utility" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="it.sistinf.ediweb.model.RequestCharge" %>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/displaytag.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css"/>
<LInk rel="stylesheet" href="css/webedi_thema.css">

<%--<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">--%>
<LInk rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.theme5.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/claro.css">
<LInk rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables/datatable.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<%
    // Per non far fare il caching...
    response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    String lingua = (String) javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.get(request.getSession(), javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.FMT_LOCALE);
    request.setAttribute("Autorizza", Bean_Dati.getListaRisultati("ListaCertificazioniNonLette"));

%>

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src='js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

<script>
    require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkAutorizza() {
        if (isCheckboxChecked2('item') == false) {
            alert('<fmt:message key="no_doc_aut" />');
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('aut').value = "true";
            document.getElementById('notaRifiuto').value = "";
            document.forms.inboxform.action = "edi.do?serv=Q.2";
            document.forms.inboxform.submit();
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkRifiuta() {
        if (isCheckboxChecked2('item') == false) {
            alert('<fmt:message key="no_doc_aut" />');
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('aut').value = "false";

            document.forms.inboxform.action = "edi.do?serv=Q.3";
            document.forms.inboxform.submit();
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-content">

        <form name="inboxform" action="edi.do?serv=Q.2" method=post onsubmit="javascript:return checkAutorizza()">
            <input type="hidden" name="autorizza" value="" id="aut">
            <input type="hidden" name="notaRifiuto" value="" id="notaRifiuto">
            <table id="autorizza" border="0" class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 100%!important">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input id="myCheck" onclick="changeBoxAll(this)" type="checkbox"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="emittente_fatt"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="mandataria"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="id"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="numero_fatt"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="data_invio"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="data_approvazione"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="data_documento"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="totale_fattura"/></th>
                        <th><fmt:message key="stato"/></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <%

                    //int count = 0;

                    //List l = (List) Bean_Dati.getListaRisultati("Autorizza");
                    //List l = (List) Bean_Dati.getListaRisultati("ListaCertificazioniNonLette");
                    //List l = (List) Bean_Dati.getListaRisultati("ListaCertificazioniNonLette");
                    List l = (List) request.getSession().getAttribute("requestChargeList");



                    //String trClass = "odd";
                    for (Iterator iterator = l.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                        //String evenOrOdd = "";

                        RequestCharge ci = (RequestCharge) iterator.next();
                        //if (trClass.equals("odd")) trClass = "even";
                        //else trClass = "odd";

                        /*
                        if ((count & 1) == 0) {

                            evenOrOdd = "even";
                        } else {

                            evenOrOdd = "odd";
                        }
                        count++;
                        */


                %>


                <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="">
                    <td>
                        <%if (ci.isAutorizza() && ci.isMaster()) {%>
                        <input class="myCheck" name="item" type="checkbox" id="<%=ci.getPk_coda()%>"
                               value="<%=ci.getPk_coda()%>"
                        <%}%></td>
                    <td>
                        <%if (ci.isAutorizza() && ci.isMaster()) {%>
                        <img
                                onclick="changeBoxAll2(document.getElementById('myCheck')); openDialog('edi.do?serv=3.B&pk='+'<%=ci.getPk_coda()%>'+'&canale=WEB&autorizza=si','680px','500px','9')"
                                width="16px" src="img/icona_vedidocumento.png" align=left border=0 alt="Visualizza">
                        <%} else {%>
                        <img
                                onclick="openDialog2('edi.do?serv=3.B&pk='+'<%=ci.getPk_coda()%>'+'&canale=WEB&autorizza=no','680px','500px','9')"
                                width="16px" src="img/icona_vedidocumento.png" align=left border=0 alt="Visualizza">
                        <%}%>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=ci.getDesc_unita1()%>
                    </td>


                    <td><%=(ci.getFornitore() != null ? ci.getFornitore() : (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("mandataria"))%>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=ci.getPk_coda()%>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=ci.getNum_doc()%>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=(ci.getData_in() != null ? ci.getData_in().substring(8, 10) + "/" + ci.getData_in().substring(5, 7) + "/" + ci.getData_in().substring(0, 4) : "") %>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=(ci.getData_app() != null ? ci.getData_app().substring(8, 10) + "/" + ci.getData_app().substring(5, 7) + "/" + ci.getData_app().substring(0, 4) : "")%>
                    </td>
                    <td><%=(ci.getData_doc() != null ? ci.getData_doc().substring(8, 10) + "/" + ci.getData_doc().substring(5, 7) + "/" + ci.getData_doc().substring(0, 4) : "")%>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right"><%=(ci.getTot_fattura()!=null?Utility.getImportFormatLanguage(ci.getTot_fattura(), lingua):"")%></td>
                    <td title="<%=(ci.getMotivoRifiuto()!=null?ci.getMotivoRifiuto():"")%>"><%=ci.getStato()%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%} %>


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <% if (Bean_Dati.getNumeroRecord("Autorizza") != 0) {%>
        <div class="bottoneDiv">
            <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="<fmt:message key="autorizza" />"
                   onclick="Javascript: checkAutorizza();"/>

            <%--<input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="<fmt:message key="rifiuta" />"--%>
            <%--onclick="Javascript: checkRifiuta();"/>--%>
        </div>
        <% } %>


        <div id="dialog" title="">

            <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="630px" src="" id="myFrame">


            </iframe>

        </div>

        <div id="dialogReject" title="">
            <%--<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200px" src="" id="myFrameReject">--%>
            <table style="visibility: hidden;" id="rifiutaTable" border="0" class="standard-table-cls"
                   style="width: 100%!important">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Inserire note ri rifiuto</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea style="visibility: hidden;" rows="5" cols="50" id="myRejectNote"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="<fmt:message key="rifiuta" />"
                               onclick="rifiuta()"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%--</iframe>--%>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml as well as the header part of the JSP using the fmt taglib?

Comment: Similar to this - can you check if you have everything in place - web.xml, taglib directive, fmt:bundle or fmt:setBundle etc. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274765/reading-properties-file-from-jstl

Comment: @swinkler I edit my original post putting it my web.xl file and the code of my view

Comment: Done, but it still don't work. I updated the web.xml file in my original post, as you can see I also added the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext

Comment: Please read my answer - the taglib is not registered in your web.xml!

Comment: If you see my updated web.xml you can see that I have added this taglib by the tag that you have posted to me. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to make it clear in my answer what is still missing. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Your JSP requires two taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld" prefix="display" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

You web.xml does not load the second taglib - must look like this and contain **two taglib entries**:

```
<taglib> 
    <taglib-uri>http://displaytag.sf.net</taglib-uri> 
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

And provide a folder `WEB-INF/lib` containing the `fmt.tld`.

Comment: and where have I to take the fmt.tld file? In the first application I have not this file but it works

Comment: You can download it - it is part of the jstl.jar. You might find it in your project or in the web container you are using. It is packed in the JAR/META-INF - otherwise please google for the fmt.tld download.