# fmt tag not able to read property file in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, properties, jstl

I have an application where the jsp file tries to read data from property file with the help of fmt tag like

```
<li id="username.${message.key}"><fmt:message                                       key="${message.key}">
```

The message key is set in a property file named xxx_en.properties and the property file is located at the location **JavaSource/resources/xxx_en.propeties**

In my spring context file, I have also mapped the property file as :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/resources/xxx_en" />
```

But the application is not able to read the property file xxx_en.properties at all. Instead of showing the vale from property in jsp, it's showing  " ??key?? ", where key is the key=value pair in property file. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274765/reading-properties-file-from-jstl) answer?

Comment: @amdg : Thank u so much. I have gone through the link which you have provided and one of the solution worked. I have included the <fmt:bundle> tag also with <fmt:message tag> . Though it's quite strange that for some of the jsps, just the <fmt:message> is working perfectly fine while for some of the jsps without <fmt:bunlde> tag it isn't working. Thanks anyway for the help. Really appreciate it.